# Crystal Report load report failed using C# & SQL Azure

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

I have made a project using C# .NET Framework in Visual Studio 2019. I have used Crystal Reports 2008 for Reporting & SQL Azure for Database.
I have added reports in my project Resources & then called on. Here is the code of Load Function of Report Form.

```
        ConnectionInfo con = new ConnectionInfo();
        if (VAR == "ChofAcc")
        {

            chofac1.SetDatabaseLogon(con.UserID,con.Password,con.ServerName,con.DatabaseName);
            crystalReportviewer2.ReportSource = chofac1;
            foreach (ReportObject ro in chofac1.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects)
            {
                if ((ro.Kind == ReportObjectKind.FieldObject && ro.Name == "hed1"))
                {
                    ((FormulaFieldDefinition)((FieldObject)ro).DataSource).Text = "'" + checkusersfrm.header + "'";
                }
            }

        }
```

It works absolutely fine but when I install my ClickOnce & CR_Runtime_32_bit & 64_bit on Client's system, it gives the following error.

[image: Error Screenshot]